# Owl carousel как спозиционировать стрелки навигации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка, owl-carousel

Добрый день, уважаемые.

В процессе верстки столкнулся с такой проблемой. При замене стандартных стрелок навигации в owl слайдере и позиционирования их по краям слайдера вся эта область навигации накладываеться поверх картинок (показал на фото), поскольку задаю ширину `width:100%`, после чего, разумеется, нету возможности нажать на картинки слайдера (если они, допустим, являются ссылками на другие продукт).

Как это исправить? Стрелки должны быть прижаты к краям слайдера при изменении размеров экрана.

Может, есть статья, где описывается как с данным слайдером работать правильно? Я в документации читал, что можно через JS заменять эти стрелки, но в данном случае они композиционные (стрелочка и подложка), и тут такое не прокатит.

Для примера:

```js
$(".owl-carousel-2").owlCarousel({

  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  autoplay: false,
  // margin: 5,
  navText: true,
  stopOnHover: true,
  smartSpeed: 1000, //Время движения слайда
  autoplayTimeout: 4000, //Время смены слайда
  pagination: false,
  responsiveClass: true,
  responsive: {
    1200: {
      items: 8
    },
    992: {
      items: 6
    },
    320: {
      items: 4
    }


  }
});
```

```css
.brand-baner {
  padding: 20px 0;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-banner__slider,
.brand-baner__slider {
  position: relative;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #202020;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 38px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:before,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2MZ.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover:before,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover:before {
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2Jk.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #202020;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:before,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2Mj.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:hover,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:hover {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:hover:before,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:hover:before {
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2Mv.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="brand-baner">
  <div class="brand-baner__slider owl-carousel-2  owl-carousel">
    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image1" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image2" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image3" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image4" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image5" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image6" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image7" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image8" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image9" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- некорректно отрабатывающий слайдер, нету возможности нажать на ссылку перехода. [введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmQ6L.png)

Comment: почему бы просто не создать 2 блока с кнопками?

Comment: можно удалить owl-nav а кнопки с него перенести в owi-stage-outer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я это делаю так: выставляем для `.owl-nav {height:0}` и позиционируем абсолютно по центру. Кнопки так же позиционируем абсолютно c `top:-25px;` и разводим по краям через `left:0px;` и `right:0px;`.

Рабочий пример:

```js
$(".owl-carousel-2").owlCarousel({

  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  autoplay: false,
  // margin: 5,
  navText: true,
  stopOnHover: true,
  smartSpeed: 1000, //Время движения слайда
  autoplayTimeout: 4000, //Время смены слайда
  pagination: false,
  responsiveClass: true,
  responsive: {
    1200: {
      items: 8
    },
    992: {
      items: 6
    },
    320: {
      items: 4
    }


  }
});
```

```css
.brand-baner {
  padding: 20px 0;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-banner__slider,
.brand-baner__slider {
  position: relative;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: -25px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #202020;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 38px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:before,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2MZ.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover:before,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover:before {
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2Jk.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -25px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #202020;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:before,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2Mj.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:hover,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:hover {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.main-banner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:hover:before,
.brand-baner__slider .owl-nav .owl-next:hover:before {
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2Mv.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="brand-baner">
  <div class="brand-baner__slider owl-carousel-2  owl-carousel">
    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image1" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image2" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image3" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image4" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image5" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image6" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image7" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image8" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-baner__item">
      <div class="brand-baner__wp-img">
        <a href="#"> <img class="brand-baner__pic" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x64/99cccc.gif&text=The+image9" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ну, и как вариант, можете использовать кастомные кнопки навигации и забиндить на них переключение слайдер. Подробнее читайте [тут](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html).